# Javascript: Issues with Marquee (logo slider) Animation

Tags: javascript, marquee

Having a problem with one line of code in a JavaScript. The idea is to do a dynamic scrolling logo marquee, but the value I have for translateX seems to be invalid:

> Keyframe property value 'translateX(-${translateValue}px)' is invalid according to the syntax for “transform”.

Here's the entire script. I did try change the -${translateValue} to a hard value like -100px or -100% and that does work, but it makes the animation jump at a point. So that's a problem to be sure.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const initSlider = () => {
    const list = document.querySelector('#brands-slider-{{ section.id }} .brands-slider-list')
    const listLength = list.querySelectorAll('.brands-slider-item').length
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', list.innerHTML)
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', list.innerHTML)
  
    let translateValue = 0
  
    document.querySelectorAll('#brands-slider-{{ section.id }} .brands-slider-item').forEach((item, index) => {
      if (index >= listLength) {
        item.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true')
    }
      translateValue = item.clientWidth + translateValue
    })
    translateValue = translateValue / 4
  
    const animation = list.animate([
      { transform: 'translateX(0)' },
      { transform: 'translateX(-${translateValue}px)' }     
    ], {
      duration: {{ section.settings.animation_duration | times:1000 }},
      iterations: Infinity
    });
  
  list.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    animation.pause()
  })
  list.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    animation.play()
  })
}
initSlider()

document.addEventListener('shopify:section:load', (e) => {
  if (e.target.querySelector('#brands-slider-{{ section.id }}')) {
    initSlider()
  }
})
```

})

Comment: Did you mean to use back ticks instead of single quotes

Comment: My bad. It should be single quotes as in the code example. I'll edit that.